# AWS cognito pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have integrated API Gateway with Cognito for token based authentication
The Oauth flow is client_credential.

Have followed below link to do API Gateway and Cognito integration

[Part 1 : Securing AWS API Gateway using AWS Cognito OAuth2 scopes](https://medium.com/@awskarthik82/part-1-securing-aws-api-gateway-using-aws-cognito-oauth2-scopes-410e7fb4a4c0) (medium.com)

As I have not created any user its not clear via was Cognito pricing the cost this integration will incur

1.Does AWS charge every token as a MAU? Want to understand this token generation charge

Comment: Did you check https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/

Comment: Yes. Its not clear from it.

Comment: There is no "token generation charge" as you put it. Only active and inactive users. Pretty much any action you take with a user will make that user active for that month (=1 MAU). Any subsequent actions doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Thanks IPPI. Thats correct. I figured it via checking my bill for month

Comment: AbhishekKumar or @ippi This question is currently unanswered. If you guys have figured it out, please provide the answer below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito charges only for active and inactive user only. Every active user is considered 1 MAU. Further any action taken by this user has no price implication. AWS only charges on MAU basis.